# c++ std vector initialize with existing objects

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

Below is some code that contains some already created `Location` objects and updates them. Then it needs to construct a `std::vector` of those objects to pass to other functions.

The way I construct the `vector` looks cleaner as it is a initializer list and is one line, instead of using 3 `push_back` calls after initializing an empty vector. Since we know all the elements that are going in to the vector already at construction time.

However, this leads to 2 copies being made per element. Firstly, why are there two copies being made in this line? Is the initializer list first constructor with copies, and then the vector constructor is called, therefore a second copy?
`std::vector<Location> pointsVec {l1, l2, l3};`

And secondly, is there a vector constructor or another technique to initialize the vector with only 1 copy? (I want to make exactly 1 copy as I still want to use the local objects)

```
struct Location 
{
    Location(int x, int y, std::string frame)
    : x(x)
    , y(y)
    , frame(std::move(frame))
    {
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    Location(const Location & other)
    : x(other.x)
    , y(other.y)
    , frame(other.frame)
    {
        std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Location(Location && other)
    : x(std::move(other.x))
    , y(std::move(other.y))
    , frame(std::move(other.frame))
    {
        std::cout << "move ctor" << std::endl;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    std::string frame;
};

int main ()
{
    // local objects 
    Location l1 {1, 2, "local"};
    Location l2 {3, 4, "global"};
    Location l3 {5, 6, "local"};
    
    // code that updates l1, l2, l3
    // .
    // .
    // .

    // construct vector 
    std::vector<Location> pointsVec {l1, l2, l3}; // 2 copies per element 

    std::vector<Location> pointsVec1;
    pointsVec1.push_back(l1);
    pointsVec1.push_back(l2);
    pointsVec1.push_back(l3); // 1 copy per element 
    
    return 0;
}
```

edit: this question was in general for objects that are expensive to copy. adding a string to this struct to demonstrate that point

edit: adding sample move ctor

Comment: Are you asking specifically about the shown class or generally, e.g. about classes which have members that are more costly to copy? Because I doubt that the copies make any significant difference in this case.

Comment: Any reason you don't just get rid of the distinct objects and use `std::vector<Location> pointsVec {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};` to being with?

Comment: for small objects it doesnt matter, for large objects I would never place them in a vector, instead place them on the heap and use `vector<shared_ptr>`

Comment: @NathanOliver I want to keep the distinct objects because I need to use them in the local scope. For instance, I might construct two or more vectors, with different combinations of the local objects to send to different threads. In short, I need to make 1 copy but not more.

Comment: Btw, for this particular class, there is no need to define all these constructors. Only the first constructor, the rest is defaulted.

Comment: Also, note that in your constructor, you are copying your "expensive-to-copy" object.

Comment: @mfnx of course they are, this is an example to verify how many copies are being made. I am not actually defining the copy and move ctors in the real application

Comment: If you change code due to a comment, it wouldn't be wrong to say so, or upvote the comment. That way, the comment doesn't look erroneous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a vector constructor or another technique to initialize the vector with only 1 copy?

If you move the local objects into an array, you can construct the vector from that array, eg:

```
// local objects 
Location locs[3]{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };
    
// code that updates locs ...

// construct vector 
std::vector<Location> pointsVec {locs, locs+3};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/0iWdaU)

Another option would be to simply get rid of the local objects altogether, construct them inside the `vector` to begin with, and then just refer to those elements, eg:

```
// construct vector 
std::vector<Location> pointsVec{ {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6} };

// local objects 
Location &l1 = pointsVec[0];
Location &l2 = pointsVec[1];
Location &l3 = pointsVec[2];
    
// code that updates l1, l2, l3 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Initializer lists imply a copy. There's no way around this.

You can replace one of the two copies with a move, by writing `{std::move(l1), std::move(l2), std::move(l3)}` in the initializer. Note that, since your `Location` defines a custom copy constructor, it doesn't actually have a move constructor and will fall back to the copy.

If you want to avoid all copies, you instead have to move the elements into the vector one by one.

```
std::vector<Location> pointsVec;
pointsVec.reserve(3); // or else you get more copies/moves when the vector rellocates
pointsVec.push_back(std::move(l1));
pointsVec.push_back(std::move(l2));
pointsVec.push_back(std::move(l3));
```

But let's face it: your little class is 2 `int`s large. There is no real cost to the copies (and no advantage in moving over copying), and I mean that literally: chances are, the compiler will just optimize all of the copying away.

Comment: good points, but as long as the copy constructor has side effects, such as printing to the console, the compiler will not optimize the copies away

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The compiler is allowed to optimize copies away even if that deletes side effects.

Comment: Moving 2 ints from the local object to the vector is the same as copying them. It's not that there is no advantage in moving over copying... they get copied anyways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all three `Location` objects inside the vector, and you want them in `L1`, `L2`, `L3`, you definitely need to make a copy - three objects cannot be in six places, twice each.

If you don’t need the `l1`, `l2`, `l3` instances in your local code afterwards, you could *move* them instead, by putting `std::move()` around them in the vector initialization. This is a big risk, however, because the variables seem to be still there and you might later add code that accesses them, with ugly consequences.

The better approach would be to construct them right in the vector initialization call instead of making temporary variables:
`{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};`.

Comment: I understand that I need to make one copy because I need both the local objects, and the objects in the vector. However, the vector initialization I've shown makes two copies per element.

Comment: You detailed the question a lot after I answered. - you cannot avoid another copying to the initializer list, because the standard says so. Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list, (about a dozen lines down:) "...each element is copy-initialized...". That's how they wrote it...

Answer (score 1):

For this case, you could use a combination of `reserve`, to avoid copies due to reallocation of the vector elements, and `emplace_back`, so you would end up with 3 new constructions, but no copies:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/vPsWh1Eod)

```cpp
    std::vector<Location> pointsVec1;
    pointsVec1.reserve(3);
    pointsVec1.emplace_back(l1.x, l1.y);
    pointsVec1.emplace_back(l2.x, l2.y);
    pointsVec1.emplace_back(l3.x, l3.y); // 1 ctor per element
```